# PostgreSQL Materialized Path / Ltree to hierarchical JSON-object

Tags: json, postgresql, tree, materialized-path-pattern, ltree

I have this materialized path tree structure built using PostgreSQL's ltree module.

- id1
- id1.id2
- id1.id2.id3
- id1.id2.id5
- id1.id2.id3.id4 ... etc

I can of course easily use ltree to get all nodes from the entire tree or from a specific path/subpath, but when I do that, naturally what I get is a lot of rows (which equals to an array/slice of nodes in the end.. Golang/whatever programming language you use)

What I'm after is to fetch the tree - ideally from a certain start and ending path/point - as a hieracical JSON tree object like etc

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "path": "1",
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "path": "1.2",
      "name": "Node 2",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "path": "1.2.3",
          "name": "Node 3",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 4,
              "path": "1.2.3.4",
              "name": "Node 4",
              "children": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "path": "1.2.5",
          "name": "Node 5",
          "children": [

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I know from a linear (non-hiearchical) row/array/slice resultset I can of course in Golang explode the path and make the necessary business logic there to create this json, but it'll certainly be MUCH much better if there's a handy way of achieving this with PostgreSQL directly.

So how would you in PostgreSQL output an ltree tree structure to json - potentionally from a starting to ending path?

If you don't know ltree, I guess the question could be generalized more to "Materalized path tree to hierachical json"

Also I'm playing with the thought of adding a parent_id on all nodes in addition to the ltree path, since at least then I would be able to use recursive calls using that id to fetch the json I guess... also I've thought about putting a trigger on that parent_id to manage the path (keep it updated) based on when a change in parent id happens - I know it's another question, but perhaps you could tell me your opinion as well, about this?

I hope some genius can help me with this. :)

For your convenience here's a sample create script you can use to save time:

```
CREATE TABLE node
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  path ltree NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT node_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO node (path,name) 
VALUES ('1','root');

INSERT INTO node (path,name) 
VALUES ('1.2','Node 1');

INSERT INTO node (path,name) 
VALUES ('1.2.3','Node 3');

INSERT INTO node (path,name) 
VALUES ('1.2.3.4','Node 4');

INSERT INTO node (path,name) 
VALUES ('1.2.5','Node 5');
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find and slightly change it to work with ltree's materialized paths instead of parent ids like often used on adjacency tree structures.

While I still hope for a better solution, this I guess will get the job done.

I kinda feel I have to add the parent_id in addition to the ltree path, since this is of course not any way near as fast as referencing parent id's.

Well credits goes to this guy's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683134/3973406), and here's my slightly modified code using ltree's subpath, ltree2text and nlevel to achieve the exact same:

```
WITH RECURSIVE c AS (
    SELECT *, 1 as lvl
    FROM node
    WHERE id=1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT node.*, c.lvl + 1 as lvl
    FROM node
    JOIN c ON ltree2text(subpath(node.path,nlevel(node.path)-2 ,nlevel(node.path))) = CONCAT(subpath(c.path,nlevel(c.path)-1,nlevel(c.path)),'.',node.id)
),
maxlvl AS (
  SELECT max(lvl) maxlvl FROM c
),
j AS (
    SELECT c.*, json '[]' children
    FROM c, maxlvl
    WHERE lvl = maxlvl
  UNION ALL
    SELECT (c).*, json_agg(j) children FROM (
      SELECT c, j
      FROM j
      JOIN c ON ltree2text(subpath(j.path,nlevel(j.path)-2,nlevel(j.path))) = CONCAT(subpath(c.path,nlevel(c.path)-1,nlevel(c.path)),'.',j.id)
    ) v
    GROUP BY v.c
)
SELECT row_to_json(j)::text json_tree
FROM j
WHERE lvl = 1;
```

There is a big problem with this solution though, so far.. see the image below for the error (Node 5 is missing):

[image: Node 5 is missing from the JSON object]

Comment: know it's been a while, but did you ever come up with the right query...?

Comment: Did you figure out the `Node 5` problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason node 5 does not show up is because it is a leaf node that is not at the max level and the subsequent join on condition excluded it.

The true base case for recursing through a tree is a node that is a leaf. By starting at the max level, that implicitly selects all leaf nodes but misses leaf nodes that occur at a lower level. Here is what we want to do in pseudo code:

```
for each node:
   if node is leaf, then return empty array
   else return the aggregated children
```

I found this hard to express in SQL though. Instead, I used the same strategy of starting from the max level and then moving up one level at a time. However, I added some code to handle the leaf node base case when I was above the max level.

Here is what I came up with:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE c AS (
  SELECT
    name,
    path,
    nlevel(path) AS lvl
  FROM node
),
maxlvl AS (
  SELECT max(lvl) maxlvl FROM c
),
j AS (
  SELECT
    c.*,
    json '[]' AS children
  FROM c, maxlvl
  WHERE lvl = maxlvl
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    (c).*,
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(j) > 0 -- check if returned record is null
        THEN json_agg(j) -- if not null, aggregate
      ELSE json '[]' -- if null, then we are a leaf, so return empty array
    END AS children
  FROM (
    SELECT
      c,
      CASE
        WHEN c.path = subpath(j.path, 0, nlevel(j.path) - 1) -- c is a parent of the child
          THEN j
        ELSE NULL -- if c is not a parent, return NULL to trigger base case
      END AS j
    FROM j
    JOIN c ON c.lvl = j.lvl - 1
  ) AS v
  GROUP BY v.c
)
SELECT row_to_json(j)::text AS json_tree
FROM j
WHERE lvl = 1;
```

My solution only uses the `path` (and the derived level from the path). It does not need `name` or `id` to properly recurse.

Here is the result I get (I included a node 6 to make sure I handled multiple leaf nodes at the same level):

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "path": "1",
  "lvl": 1,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Node 1",
      "path": "1.2",
      "lvl": 2,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Node 5",
          "path": "1.2.5",
          "lvl": 3,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Node 3",
          "path": "1.2.3",
          "lvl": 3,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Node 6",
              "path": "1.2.3.4",
              "lvl": 4,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Node 4",
              "path": "1.2.3.4",
              "lvl": 4,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```